# Allow diamond moderators to create tag synonyms on their meta sites from the synonyms page?

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms, per-site-meta

Over on [Robotics Meta](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/), I have just tried to create a tag synonym of [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) for [tagging](/questions/tagged/tagging)<sup>†</sup> since there seems to be some confusion as to which to use, and people end up adding both.

<sup>† Although looking at the tag synonyms of [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) here, I should probably have done it the other way around.</sup>

Instead of just creating the synonym as I expected, it showed me [voting buttons](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/tags/synonyms) (which obviously I couldn't vote on myself) as if I were not a moderator. I guess I should have noticed that the button said "Suggest" rather than "Create", but elsewhere on the site, diamond moderator 'suggestions' are rather more binding. *8')

It was then suggested that I needed to do this via the moderation tools, so I had a hunt around and managed to find the moderator tool for tag synonyms and approve my own synonym from there. I now see however that just clicking on the [see all tag synonyms »](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) link would have taken me there anyway.

It seems odd that we can't just create the tag synonym directly from the tag synonym page, and the suggestion mechanism breaks the expectation of moderator suggestions being immediately binding (like flags), so it would be nice if this behaviour could be made more consistent.

- <sub>Incidentally, I fully expect this to be [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), and rightly so since *it only saves one click*, but at least this post will serve as a searchable answer for future diamond moderators who are confused about this. *8')</sub>

Answer (score 9):

You probably tried to create the synonym on the wrong page, the tag synonym UI is extremely misleading for moderators.

The page where you can unilaterally create a synonym and view all existing ones is

```
/tags/synonyms
```

If you go through the tag itself and click on synonym, you can only suggest a synonym even as a moderator.

I think you should be able to remove the synonym suggestion and create it directly on that overview page, but the whole thing is rather confusing.

Comment: Thanks @MadScientist I was just editing my question to take your chat comment into account.

Comment: Incidentally, as I say in my revised question, I just needed to go to overview page and approve my own suggestion. *8')